# The multi-part identifier not working during insertion

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table WEL
(
pipe_type varchar(30),date DATE
)


insert into WEL values(H.T.NO.2,....,....)
```

getting error  `multi-part identifier h.t.no.2  could not be bound and 2 is a incorrect syntax`

is there  any problem with varchar or any other way to insert H.T.NO.2 into table

Comment: enclose your varchar in  single inverted comma before inserting like this...`'H.T.NO.2'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Character Type Data Types we must give single quotes

For inserting a single record we have two options

**First one**

insert into WEL values('H.T.NO.2','2013-07-07');

**Second one**

insert into WEL(pipe_type,date) values('H.T.NO.2','2013-07-07');

This will helpful when *default* value is given.For example

If i give *default* value for date like '2000-02-02'.Then we will write query like this

insert into WEL(pipe_type) values('H.T.NO.2');

Then system takes *default* value which you give(like 2000-02-02 ) for that one.

**Importance of Delimiter(;):**

I observe that you didn't give ";" .If so, The database  checks for another query.So for one query its not an important,But for multiple its very Important.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enclose `varchar` and `date` values in single quotes:

```
insert into WEL values('H.T.NO.2', '2013-12-31')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following format to insert the string into database:

```
insert into WEL values('H.T.NO.2',....,....);
```

Always enclose the string with Quota mark.

Answer (score 0):

As given in other answers you need to put values in single qoutes.

The error message

```
multi-part identifier h.t.no.2 could not be bound
```

is coming because MySQL is reading `h.t.no.2` as a column name rather than a string value